# Google Sheets List Unique Values After a String

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've a list of text that goes like this:

```
SME:ABC
SME:BBC
SME:CBG
SME:ABC
SME:BBC
```

I want to list the unique values after `SME:`
I used this `=UNIQUE(C2:C)`
But how to discard `SME:` from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,":(.*)"))))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the entire thing in a REGEXREPLACE

```
=REGEXREPLACE(UNIQUE(C2:C), "SME\:", "" )
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en

Comment: It's working, is there a way to list automatically? Instead of dragging the formula to the next cell...

Comment: You could write a custom function in google app script, not sure how else it could be achieved.

Comment: For the script, I actually covered this function in a YouTube tutorial, the replace starts at around 27min 20 seconds https://youtu.be/3zQkPpdw3Jw

Comment: For the formula, you can just wrap it in ArrayFormula()

Comment: if I drag and drop, it includes duplicate values of the adjacent field which kinda defeats the purpose